# Parse.com Energy Impact?

Tags: xcode, debugging, parse-platform, ios9, energy

in my app I'm using the popular service Parse.com and I noticed that it is giving me some problems of energy impact ...

I did some tests and the problem of the energy (that we can all see in xcode in Debag Navigator) is displayed when I insert in AppDelegate the prompts to enter my account number and ID of the APP Parse.com ... Someone He has noticed this problem? why this strong consumption ?? you can 'do about it? I would find myself with memory and battery problems during the development of my app ...

[image]

I show you the code colpevo my strange energy impact (I only files in my app I just started so it is not even a big overage)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APP_ID
                 clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];


    return YES;
}
```